# Matching Same Hebrew Words Always Return False

Tags: java, android

I was trying to matched same Hebrew words with each other but it always calls else part of program.

Here what i actually tried in code:

> Calling a method by passing a Hebrew word(Coming from string.xml)

```
<string name="shevat" >שְׁבָט‬</string>

getCurrentMonthIndex("שְׁבָט")
```

> Below method always return false

```
private boolean getCurrentMonthIndex(String month) {
    if (month.equals("שְׁבָט")) {
        Log.d("Result:", "equal");
        return true;
    } else {
        Log.d("Result:", "not equal");
        return false;
    }
}
```

> If i hardcoded the value then it return true

```
private boolean getCurrentMonthIndex(String month) {
    if ("שְׁבָט".equals("שְׁבָט")) {
        Log.d("Result:", "equal");
        return true;
    } else {
        Log.d("Result:", "not equal");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It means that month variable is not same as your hebrew string in piece of code 2.

Comment: It contain the same words and here is the log https://prnt.sc/mgx9zg

Comment: Where is the string month coming from? Is it typed by hand into an input? It may have something to do with RTL text but I'm not sure...

Comment: It is coming from string.xml file and if i call the method by hardcoded value  then it return true.

Comment: Trying comparing the bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string resource has one more Unicode character which is not visible.

This is your string on resource: https://www.fontspace.com/unicode/analyzer/?q=%D7%A9%D6%B0%D7%81%D7%91%D6%B8%D7%98%E2%80%AC

This is your string on code: https://www.fontspace.com/unicode/analyzer/?q=%D7%A9%D6%B0%D7%81%D7%91%D6%B8%D7%98

The extra character is U+202C POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING.

I encountered similar problem while comparing Arabic strings. In my case, the invisible character was U+200E LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK.

Before comparing strings, I trimmed this character from them. You can also trim POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING. Also you can try to remove this character from resource file by using a hex editor.

In case of the links are not working, unicode analyze of your string:

```
U+05E9  HEBREW LETTER SHIN
U+05B0  HEBREW POINT SHEVA
U+05C1  HEBREW POINT SHIN DOT
U+05D1  HEBREW LETTER BET
U+05B8  HEBREW POINT QAMATS
U+05D8  HEBREW LETTER TET
U+202C  POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING //only on resource file
```

I don't know much about Hebrew but I think you can encounter another problem also in the future. In your word first letter has two modifiers: U+05B0 HEBREW POINT SHEVA and 0+05C1 HEBREW POINT SHIN DOT. 
Even though two letters below look exactly same, they are not equal. The modifiers are written on different order.

שְׁ : U+05E9 + U+05B0 + U+05C1

שְׁ : U+05E9 + U+05C1 + U+05B0

I encountered similiar problem on Arabic. Even thought two words below look identical, they are not equal to each other. U+064E ARABIC FATHA and U+0651 ARABIC SHADDA are written on different orders.

رَّ : U+0631 + U+064E + U+0651

رَّ : U+0631 + U+0651 + U+064E

For Arabic, on my typescript project, I wrote an utility method to normalize strings before comparing them. Normalization method removes all LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK characters and reorders modifier characters in a standard way. I think you may need to do similar thing for Hebrew.

[@Elias N](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54535158/54536263#comment95885723_54536263) has pointed out that Java already has a method to normalize strings. This method does not remove POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING or LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK.

```
String a = "שְׁ";  //U+05E9 + U+05B0 + U+05C1
String b = "שְׁ";  //U+05E9 + U+05C1 + U+05B0

String nomrA = java.text.Normalizer.normalize(a, java.text.Normalizer.Form.NFC);
String nomrB = java.text.Normalizer.normalize(b, java.text.Normalizer.Form.NFC);

assertFalse("Original strings are not equal.", a.equals(b));
assertTrue("Normalized strings are equal.", normA.equals(normB));
```

Comment: you might also want to check this on normalization: http://unicode.org/faq/normalization.html with this being the java implementation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/normalizerapi.html

Comment: @EliasN thanks for the information. I've tried Java API to compare the Arabic and Hebrew words and it works perfectly for different unicode orders. But it does not remove  POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING and LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK.

Comment: right, normalization by unicode's definition provides a consistent sequence of bytes for visually similar characters, but it will not remove unintentional or invisible characters such as those you have mentioned

Answer (score 1):

IDE default character set is 'CP1252'. so it will not be able to read this non-english character. does your IDE supports UTF-8 character set, if yes then it should return true.
Like, if i copy this code to Eclipse (by changing log to sysout) then its working for me.

Comment: I am using android studio and it support UTF-8

Comment: Oh,k.. if you are reading it from xml, then can you try to print (log) before comparison, so that you will be clear on what string is been passed to method.